# $g(x)=x^{1/x};\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_1^{2N}e^{i\pi t}g(t)dt=(-i)\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{2N}e^{i^2\pi t}g(1+it)dt?$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals, constants

This linked [arxiv article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3844) deals with a variant$\left(g(x)=x^{1/x};\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_1^{2N}e^{i\pi t}g(t)dt\right)$

of the [MRB constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MRBConstant.html)$\left(g(x)=x^{1/x}; \mathrm{CMRB} = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N}(-1)^ng(n)\right).$

I found a faster-converging integral for the variant:

$\left(g(x)=x^{1/x};(-i)\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{2N}e^{i^2\pi t}g(1+it)dt\text{ or }(-i)\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{2N}e^{-\pi t}g(1+it)dt.\right)$

Here is some Mathematica code with results that justifies it to me:

```
  g[x_] = x^(1/x); Print[g[x_] = x^(1/x); 
 Timing[MKB = 
NIntegrate[Exp[I Pi t] (g[t]), {t, 1, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 200, PrecisionGoal -> 200] - 
 I/Pi][[1]]]; Print[g[x_] = x^(1/x); 
 Timing[N[MKB + (I NIntegrate[
    Exp[I^2 Pi t] (g[1 + t I]), {t, 0, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 200, PrecisionGoal -> 200] + I/Pi)]]]



 (* 1.25

  {0.890625,-1.0328794596386124*10^198+2.199848562388703*10^198 I}*)
```

I've shown the variant and my faster-converging integral to be equal to 35,000 digits at the end of this [Wolfram community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1323951?p_p_auth=RKNnS1Uh).

It would be awesome if a scholar like you would prove that the variant and my faster-converging integral are really equal. **[Eternal fame awaits you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant)** if you can help prove this.

Answer (score 1):

I got an [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-prove-for-g-x-x-1-x-lim-limits_-N-to-infty-int-limits_1-2N-e-i-pi-t-g-t-dt-i-lim-limits_-N-to-infty-int-limits_-0-2N-frac-g-1-it-exp-pi-t-dt) on Quora.
There is a lot of pretty math that might take me a while to transcribe.

I discovered that for

g(x)=x^(1/x), [image]

Here it is proved by Ariel Gershon.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Plugging in equations [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oom67.jpg) and [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSIZv.jpg) into equation [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUVz7.png) gives us:
[image]
[image]
Now take the limit as N→∞ and apply equations [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXki.jpg) and [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqmVa.jpg) :
[image]
He went on to note that

[image]